# How is an EF navigation property transferred between different classes?

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

This question is about the navigation property in an EF generated entity.

I am trying to improve my ability to more loosely couple code and have run into a problem understanding the navigation property that is so useful when using EF entities.  I am working with the code first methodology.  The code that follows is my best attempt to simulate the issue to keep the code presented here tightly focused on my question.  While we can sometimes omit something critical when we do this, because the problem I am struggling with is present below, I think the simulation is OK.

Using the following architecture with the class definitions that follow, there is a navigation property `layer1` in the layer2 entity.  In this architecture, layer1/layer2 interface directly with SQL.

[image]

```
Public Class layer1
  Public Property ID As Integer
  Public Property name As String
  Public Overridable Property layer2 As New List(Of layer2)
End Class

Public Class layer2
  Public Property ID As Integer
  Public Property name As String
  Public Property layer1ID As Integer
  Public Overridable Property layer1 As layer1   <<<< navigation property
End Class

Public Class efTestingContext
  Inherits DbContext
  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("name=efTestingContext")
    Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = False
  End Sub
  Public Property layer1 As DbSet(Of layer1)
End Class
```

This image shows what the `layer1` entity looks like after SQL data retrieval.

[image]

It can be seen that the layer2.layer1 property is in fact a layer1 type, which makes sense.

Now the following classes dlayer1/dlayer2 are added to simulate a domain layer and simulate the different architecture also shown.

```
Public Class dlayer1
  Public Property ID As Integer
  Public Property name As String
  Public Overridable Property layer2 As New List(Of dlayer2)
End Class

Public Class dlayer2
  Public Property ID As Integer
  Public Property name As String
  Public Property layer1ID As Integer
  Public Overridable Property layer1 As dlayer1   <<<< navigation property
End Class

End Class
```

[image]

This requires what I assume is often called a DTO (?) to convert `layer1` to `dlayer1`.  This simulated conversion object is shown below.

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
  Dim theLayers = db.layer1.Include("layer2").ToList()
  Dim thedLayers As New List(Of dlayer1)

  'This code simulates the storage to domain translation
  For Each layer In theLayers
    Dim aLayer As New dlayer1
    aLayer.ID = layer.ID
    aLayer.name = layer.name
    For Each subLayer In layer.layer2
      Dim aSubLayer As New dlayer2
      aSubLayer.ID = subLayer.ID
      aSubLayer.name = subLayer.name
      aSubLayer.layer1ID = subLayer.layer1ID
      aSubLayer.layer1 = subLayer.layer1   <<<< something else needs to happen. What?
      aLayer.layer2.Add(aSubLayer)
    Next
    thedLayers.Add(aLayer)
  Next

  Return View(theLayers)
End Function
```

The code above returns, of course, the following:

[image]

How do I code this so that the navigation property will be properly created in the dlayer1 entity?

I am aware of libraries such as automapper, but that seems to be focused on the domain-to-presentation interaction.  I am not aware of libraries that handle the data-to-domain interaction.  But even if there is a library that would do this, I’d still like to know how I would discretely code this.  I'm also assuming this question is equally applicable to the equivalent C# code.

Comment: Using EF simply as a CRUD tool winds up keeping everything simpler, even though that approach uses a bunch of DTOs. When querying the database, the use of anonymous objects (at least in C#) is a helpful (and often performant) way to retrieve the navigation properties as an intermediate step before building the DTO.  E.g: `context.MyObjects.Where(i => SomeCriteria).Select(n => new {a=n.a, b=n.b}).ToList().Select(dto => new DTO(dto.a,dto.b))`.  This approach should be used sparingly, but if you're retrieving records for processing in a number of different classes, it could well be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation properties often don't survive an implicit DTO mapping, because they are prone to recursion. Converting `layer1` to `dlayer1` also converts the underlying `layer2` to `dlayer2`, each of which then convert their `layer1` to `dlayer1`, and you have created infinite recursion.

There are some ways around this, but the easiest way is to simply ignore the nav props, and later recreate them based on the PK/FK properties.

*As an aside, this issue in unrelated to EF. It's related to the inability of implicitly handling circular references. Circular references generally lead to recursion, and .NET doesn't really protect you from unwanted recursion. It only raises an issue once the stack actually overflows at runtime.*

---

1. Either empty the nav props, or make sure that your mapping does not try to map the nav props.
2. Convert each object to its equivalent DTO class. There should be no problem, as they are no longer linked to any other object (or their links are being ignored by the mapping process)
3. Recreate their navigational properties by matching `dlayer1.ID` to the `dlayer2.layer1ID` property.

That is the easiest way to get around it, and the performance cost of doing so is negligible.

---

**Update for the questions in your comment.**

> Regarding point #3 - that's simply storing the parent ID value and not, as point #1 seems to say, recreating a nav prop.

Maybe I explained it badly. Let me show a quick example. Note that the code is **massively oversimplified** for the sake of brevity.

1 - Either empty the nav props, or make sure that your mapping does not try to map the nav props.

```
foreach( var child in myChildren ) { child.Parent = null; }

myParent.Children = null;
```

2 - Convert each object to its equivalent DTO class. There should be no problem, as they are no longer linked to any other object (or their links are being ignored by the mapping process)

```
foreach( var child in myChildren )
{
    myDtoChildren.Add(child.ConvertToDTO());
}

myDtoParent = myParent.ConvertToDTO();
```

3 - Recreate their navigational properties by matching `dlayer1.ID` to the `dlayer2.layer1ID` property.

```
foreach( var dtoChild in myDtoChildren )
{
    dtoChild.Parent = myDtoParent;
}

myDtoParent.Children = myDtoChildren.Where(c => c.ParentId == myDtoParent.Id);
```

In other words; you temporarily deleted the **nav prop** (the link to the other object), but you retained the **foreign key** (the `ParentId` property).
After mapping, you then use the `ParentId` (FK) property to fill in the `Parent` (nav prop) property.

> But you also said there are some ways around this. Can you elaborate?

The example above is essentially a workaround. You edit the data to avoid the problem. But there are other ways to avoid the problem.

- For XML serialization, you can add a `[XmlIgnore]` attribute to the nav prop so it does not get mapped (therefore preventing recursion).
- WCF data contracts actually don't run into recursion problems here, they are able to handle circular references.
- If you use explicit mapping rules (as opposed to implicit ones), you can simply omit the nav prop from the mapping.

Comment: The recursion you spoke of is what prompted my post, so thanks for confirming I'm dealing with a real issue, not a coding error. Also nice to know this isn't an EF issue.  Regarding point #3 - that's simply storing the parent ID value and not, as point #1 seems to say, recreating a nav prop.  But you also said there `are some ways around this`. Can you elaborate? I'm still holding out hope I can recreate the nav prop. My delayed response to your post was to research this, but I didn't see a solution I understood.  Do you have any favorite links explaining how to recreate a nav prop?

Comment: @Alan: Updated the answer. "Recreating a nav prop" is nothing more than assigning an object to it, e.g. `myBook.Author = myAuthorList.Single(a => a.Id == myBook.AuthorId);`. Nav props are nothing special. Once they are instantiated by EF, they behave just like any other (reference type) property.

Comment: Your last comment and example here was profoundly simple and answered a question for which I search hours - it's all in how it's expressed.  Thank you so much for distilling it down to this simple statement.  I'm certain anyone else who has the same lack of experience with this as I did should be able to understand the issue.  I tested this in my code above and it seems to work great.  I will translate this knowledge to my actual project and after I see it work, will come back and update my post to reflect your guidance.  Thanks again!  I also see now why this is not really EF related.